# SSRS Margin from page header for continued tables

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-tablix

When using SSRS and exporting to PDF, if a Tablix object extends beyond one page, it of course continues on to the next. Is there any way though that I can insert a margin between the page header and the continue Tablix? Currently the Tablix goes to the next page, and starts directly at the header row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do you already have a header on your page?

If not, you can add a header and on the header properties you can set to not display on the firs page (right click it -> properties)

Comment: Oh clever, I see where you're going with this. I could just extend the white space of the page header, and this could be my margin, for continued objects.